# Automatically updating next day cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fully automate my excel sheet report. so that there should not be any manual intervention

Currently, I have sheet where First row(A2: An) is Date and First column is having the team and 2 column(B2: B7) is getting Values automatically from another workbook.

I am trying to automate that Value of B2:B7 Will be filled in "C" Column if today is 01 July, if today is 02 July it should be filled in 02 July without changing the value of 01 July.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, based on the current day, you would like to update the values in column B. Are the values stored in the other worksheet, or do they write to the one in the thumbnail?

Below you may see a simple solution, but it works. Obviously you'd need to extend it until the J-column. If you have many date headers, you could do a for each loop.

I implement a variable, cDay, to read out the current day.

```
Sub test()


    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    cDay = Left(Now(), 10)
    
    With ws1
        If cDay = Str(.Range("C1").Value) Then
            .Range("B2:B7").Value = .Range("C2:C7").Value
        ElseIf cDay = Str(.Range("D1").Value) Then
            .Range("B2:B7").Value = .Range("D2:D7").Value
        ElseIf cDay = Str(.Range("E1").Value) Then
            .Range("B2:B7").Value = .Range("E2:E7").Value
        ElseIf cDay = Str(.Range("F1").Value) Then
            .Range("B2:B7").Value = .Range("F2:F7").Value
        Else
            .Range("B2:B7").Value = ""
            
      
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

As I mentioned, this solution is simple, but it solves your problem for a small dataset, This might be a slow method if you have lots of lots of data. Is this solution sufficient?

Comment: For me there will be 14 teams and date is till last of the month. I will try the above code in my report and confirm you